# How do I check if my PC exited sleep mode

Tags: c#, .net-core

All of the sources I could find, explain how to check if the PC is in sleep-mode use .NET Framework but I have to use .NET Core as my application has to be cross-platform.

I want to replicate something like the below which requires .NET Framework and can check to see if the PC left sleep mode

```
SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged += OnPowerChange;

private void OnPowerChange(object s, PowerModeChangedEventArgs e) 
{
    switch ( e.Mode ) 
    {
        case PowerModes.Resume: 
        break;
        case PowerModes.Suspend:
        break;
    }
}
```

Is there a solution that uses purely .NET Core, or is there a DLL written in C/C++ that I could import and use?

Comment: I don't get how a program would know if it is in sleep in mode, since by definition all programs are put to sleep, so a program wouldn't be able to execute any "sleep mode detection" code.

Comment: Which class or method is missing in core specifically?

Comment: .NetFramework has PowerState which .net core doesnt have or at least I don't know any equivelent to it

Comment: The docs mention it however: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.powermodes?view=netcore-2.1 But I have never worked with it anywhere ever.

Answer (score 1):

The 'PowerModeChangedEvent' may be of use to you, you can install a Nuget package for this in a .net core console application.

[image: package management screen]

You need to make sure you reference the `using Microsoft.Win32;` Namespace and you'll need to do some research (http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/DetectPowerEvents.aspx - could be useful) as to how you can apply this to your specific scenario.

Comment: Author asked for a cross platform solution, and this is Windows-only library. There is no way it will behave properly on Linux/MacOS

Answer (score 1):

Main problem with code relying on sleep mode is that every platform defines it differently, so there is no built-in solution (at least not one that one know of)

My best guess how to do it would be to write a simple library that will get power state from current system, and map it to your own `enum`.

This library will need to check what system it's running on, you can do it with

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform()
```

that will give you one of these:

```
OSPlatform.Windows
OSPlatform.OSX
OSPlatform.Linux
```

Then you will use platform specific code for each case. So:

For Windows - `Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents` with `SystemEvents.PowerModeChanged`

Lower level code for Linux, sadly I don't know specific solution, so all I can do is give you a link explaining sleep states in Linux Kernel:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.18/admin-guide/pm/sleep-states.html

As for OSX, I too have no idea. My first guess is that it should work similarly to Linux case, but maybe there is some library that does it for you.

In any case, for Linux and OSX you will need to use external C/C++ libraries that will give you sleep state, and map it to your enum.